# Hold to jump higher function not properly working

Tags: game-development, keyboard-events, godot, gdscript

I'm currently making a game and I made this simple script that checks when a player holds down the up arrow key so that the longer you hold the button, the further upwards you jump. It works fine and all, until you decide to jump again mid-air, then the gravity of the is_action_just_pressed is added into the player's total gravity which is kind of a problem.

I'm kind of new to GDScript, so a little help would really be appreciated!

Here's my (bad) code:

```
var gravity : int = 1800

var vel : Vector2 = Vector2()

func _physics_process(delta):
    
    vel.x = 0
        
    vel = move_and_slide(vel, Vector2.UP)
    
    vel.y += gravity * delta
    
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        vel.y -= jumpforce
        gravity -= 500


    if Input.is_action_just_released("jump"):
        gravity += 500
```

There isn't anything in godot for checking if the player is holding down a button and I'm not sure what is wrong with my code, so I have no idea what is causing this issue or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There isn't anything in godot for checking if the player is holding down a button

Instead of using `is_action_just_pressed` and `is_action_just_released` which tell you if the action was pressed or released since the last frame, use `is_action_pressed` which tell you if the action is currently pressed.

---

> It works fine and all, until you decide to jump again mid-air, then the gravity of the is_action_just_pressed is added into the player's total gravity which is kind of a problem.

The issue is that you are not keeping track if player jumped. For example:

```
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        jumped = true
        vel.y -= jumpforce
        gravity -= 500


    if Input.is_action_just_released("jump") and jumped:
        jumped = false
        gravity += 500
```

With `jumped` declared at the top of the script, similar to `gravity` and `vel`.